# Error running command line Mocha using jQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, mocha.js

So I have this function that uses jQuery in a file

account.js:

```
function getSession() {
  var session = null;
  $.ajax({
    url: "/ajax/get_session",
    async: false
  }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    session = data;
  });
  return session;
}
```

and I want to test it on the command line using Mocha. for this I have another file:

test-account.js:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var fs = require('fs');
var vm = require('vm');

// includes minified & uglified version, assuming mocha is run in repo root dir
var path = '../public/js/account.min.js';
var code = fs.readFileSync(path);
vm.runInThisContext(code);

describe('getSession', function() {
  it('should return the empty string because it fails', function () {
      assert.equal('', getSession());
  });
});
```

But when I run `mocha` on the command line I get the error

> 1 failing
>
> 1) getSession should return the empty string because it fails:
>
> ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>
> at getSession (evalmachine.:1:34)
>
> at Context. (test/test-account.js:19:24)

I'm a Mocha n00b, so I wasn't exactly sure the correct direction to go in to solve this. I tried adding

```
var jqueryLocalPath = 'jquery.min.js';
var jqueryCode = fs.readFileSync(jqueryLocalPath);
vm.runInThisContext(jqueryCode);
```

before the `describe` call in `test-account.js` without success. I then tried to `require` it via Node.js by running

```
npm install jquery
```

and adding

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

to the top of `test-account.js` before running `mocha`. This also did not work and I get the same error. This second method has the added disadvantage of running a newer version of jQuery (2.2.0) the the one I want to test on (1.11.3).

How can I make this test work?

Comment: I have a similar problem so I cannot solve this one for us. I might be able to help with a related problem if it comes up. I have read that Node does not include a headless browser by default, which is required to use jQuery because jQuery needs to access the DOM; therefore, a headless browser or similar is required. Jsdom is a possible solution to testing jQuery code, once jQuery is actually loaded.

Comment: You can install jquery like this: npm install jquery@1.11.3 for the rest, the answer below is good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer is to use the [correct Node modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-jsdom#usage), for testing.

```
var assert = require('assert');
var fs = require('fs');
var vm = require('vm');
var jsdom = require('mocha-jsdom'); // This is necessary for testing jQuery in Mocha

describe('mocha tests', function () {

    jsdom()

    before(function () {
        $ = require('jquery')
    });

    // includes minified & uglified version, assuming mocha is run in repo root dir
    var path = 'account.js';
    var code = fs.readFileSync(path);
    vm.runInThisContext(code);

    describe('getSession', function() {
        it('should return the empty string because it fails', function () {
            assert.equal('', getSession());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: don't forget you have to install the jsdom package